# What am I doing wrong with my code for Mclaurin Series Expansion?

Tags: c++, c++11, math, series

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LgGA.png)
I have been trying to make a code in c++ for the Mclaurin ’s Series expansion of sin(x), as a review for my Intro to Programming class and my results are always not equivalent to the sample runs. I have been trying to trouble shoot this for hours to no avail. Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
double factorial(int num);
double sum(double number, int n);
int main() {
double number, sin;
int n;
    cout<<"Enter the value of x: ";
    cin>>number;
    cout<<"Enter the number of terms: ";
    cin>>n;
    sin=sum(number,n);
    cout<<"sin("<<number<<") = "<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(6)<<sin<<endl;

    return 0;
}
double factorial(int num){
    double sum=1;
    for(int x=num; x>=1;x--){
        sum*=x;
    }
    return sum;
}
double sum(double number, int n){
    int count=3;
    double term,term1, sum=0, sum2=0, totalSum;

    for(int i=1;i<n-1;i+=2 ){
        term1=(pow(number, count))/ factorial(count);
        sum+=term1;
        count+=4;
        }
    for(int j=0;j<n-2;j+=2){
            term=pow(number, count)/ factorial(count);
            sum2+=term;
            count+=4;
        }
    totalSum=number+sum+sum2;
    return totalSum;
    }
```

Comment: You aren't doing alternating signs, and you aren't resetting `count` between the two loops. (Frankly, it's unclear why you even need two loops). You start with `x^3`, not with `x`

Comment: Hint: if `term == -x^3/3!`, then you can compute `next_term == x^5/5!` as `next_term  = -term * x * x / 4 / 5`. Rather than computing every term from scratch, it's easier to compute each subsequent term from the previous one. General formula is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is wrong with your one - it looks overcomplicated.

Here is something more simple:

```
double fact(unsigned n)
{
    double result = 1;
    do
    {
        result *= n;
    }
    while(--n);
    return result;
}

double msin(double x, unsigned n)
{
    double result = x;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        result += (i % 2 ? 1 : -1) * pow(x, 3 + 2 * i) / fact(3 + 2 * i);
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    for(unsigned n = 2; n < 10; n++)
        printf("%.30f\n%.30f\n\n", msin(1.4, n), sin(1.4));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/o3Wc8e8GY

Answer (score 0):

You don't need power or factorial functions.  It should look more like this:

```
def sine(t, n):
    result = 0.0
    term = t
    sign = 1.0
    for i in range(1, n):
        result += sign*term
        sign *= -1.0
        term *= t*t/(2*i)/(2*i+1)
    return result
```

This is Python, but you should be able to work out how to port it to C++ pretty easily.

One other thing to think about: normalizing the input angle.  Series expansions are only correct for values of x close to the expansion point 0.  You'll want to take advantage of the periodicity of the sine function.